# Calculating moving average between groups and smoothing between some groups that are continuous

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math

My apologies if the title is confusing, I will do my best to explain the problem. I have an example data set here:
[Ex.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Ady.png)

```
Segment Reach   OutSeg  Elevation
1   1   3   50
1   2   3   74
1   3   3   87
1   4   3   53
1   5   3   97
2   1   3   16
2   2   3   14
2   3   3   31
2   4   3   35
2   5   3   27
3   1   4   193
3   2   4   176
3   3   4   158
3   4   4   154
4   1   6   21
4   2   6   45
4   3   6   42
4   4   6   22
4   5   6   22
5   1   6   10
5   2   6   21
5   3   6   14
5   4   6   16
```

I would like to calculate the moving average (w a window of 3) of *Elevation* along each *Segment* number in the sequential order of its *Reach*, however, where the *Segment* has an *OutSeg* value I would like the moving average towards the end of each Segment to use *Elevation* values from the beginning of its referenced segment (OutSeg). For example, at Segment 1 Reach 5 (1,5), I would like the moving average to account for the values at (1,4), (1,5), and (3,1).

I believe some kind of for loop may be needed...I have tried the below code but it only calculates the moving average within each group:

df["moving"] = df.groupby("Segment")["Elevation"].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3,1)`df["moving"] = df.groupby("Segment")["Elevation"].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3,1)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you gave a sample data as text in the question itself, we could try to reproduce...

Comment: @SergeBallesta added! Thanks for tip

Answer (score 0):

I could not imagine a fully vectorized way, so I would just use a groupby on `Segment` applying a specific function. That function would add the first row (if any) from the `OutSeg` sub-dataframe compute the rolling meand and only return the original rows.

Code could be:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Segment', 'Reach'])  # ensure correct order

def tx(dg):
    seg = dg['Segment'].iat[0]
    outseg = dg['OutSeg'].iat[0]
    x = pd.concat([dg, df[df['Segment'] == outseg].head(1)])
    y = x['Elevation'].rolling(3, 1, center=True).mean()
    return(y[x['Segment'] == seg])

df['Mean3'] = df.groupby('Segment', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(tx)

print(df)
```

It gives:

```
    Segment  Reach  OutSeg  Elevation       Mean3
0         1      1       3         50   62.000000
1         1      2       3         74   70.333333
2         1      3       3         87   71.333333
3         1      4       3         53   79.000000
4         1      5       3         97  114.333333
5         2      1       3         16   15.000000
6         2      2       3         14   20.333333
7         2      3       3         31   26.666667
8         2      4       3         35   31.000000
9         2      5       3         27   85.000000
10        3      1       4        193  184.500000
11        3      2       4        176  175.666667
12        3      3       4        158  162.666667
13        3      4       4        154  111.000000
14        4      1       6         21   33.000000
15        4      2       6         45   36.000000
16        4      3       6         42   36.333333
17        4      4       6         22   28.666667
18        4      5       6         22   22.000000
19        5      1       6         10   15.500000
20        5      2       6         21   15.000000
21        5      3       6         14   17.000000
22        5      4       6         16   15.000000
```